# Django: Cannot resolve keyword '' into field. Choices are:

Tags: python, django, manytomanyfield

I am having this weird problem accessing `ManyToManyField`.

I have following models.

```
class Link(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length = 200)
    url = models.URLField(unique = True)
    tags = models.ManyToManyField(Tag)
    creation_date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add = True)
    user = models.ForeignKey(User)
    likes = models.ManyToManyField(User, related_name = "%(app_label)s_%(class)s_user_likes")
    dis_likes = models.ManyToManyField(User, related_name = "%(app_label)s_%(class)s_user_dis_likes")

    class Meta:
        abstract = True

class URL(Link):
    preview_image = models.URLField()
    preview_heading = models.CharField(max_length = 100)
    preview_content = models.CharField(max_length = 100)
```

When I try to access `URL.objects.get(pk=1).likes.all()`, I get `Cannot resolve keyword '' into field. Choices are:...` error.

`URL.objects.get(pk=1).tags.all(), URL.objects.get(pk=1).user` and `URL.objects.filter(likes=auser, pk=1)` work fine.

Updates:

1. The fields `likes` and `dis_likes` were added using `south` through `schemamigration`
2. Previously I was using `Django 1.6.1`, updated to `Django 1.6.2`, the problem still persists
3. Truncated the database, synced it to have fresh tables, the problem still persists
4. Partial traceback:

   ```
   File "F:\system\env\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\manager.py" in all
     133.         return self.get_queryset()
   File "F:\system\env\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\fields\related.py" in get_queryset
     549.                 return super(ManyRelatedManager, self).get_queryset().using(db)._next_is_sticky().filter(**self.core_filters)
   File "F:\system\env\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\query.py" in filter
     590.         return self._filter_or_exclude(False, *args, **kwargs)
   File "F:\system\env\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\query.py" in _filter_or_exclude
     608.             clone.query.add_q(Q(*args, **kwargs))
   File "F:\system\env\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\sql\query.py" in add_q
     1198.         clause = self._add_q(where_part, used_aliases)
   File "F:\system\env\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\sql\query.py" in _add_q
     1234.                     current_negated=current_negated)
   File "F:\system\env\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\sql\query.py" in build_filter
     1100.                     allow_explicit_fk=True)
   File "F:\system\env\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\sql\query.py" in setup_joins
     1357.             names, opts, allow_many, allow_explicit_fk)
   File "F:\system\env\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\sql\query.py" in names_to_path
     1277.                                      "Choices are: %s" % (name, ", ".join(available)))

   Exception Type: FieldError at /url/3
   Exception Value: Cannot resolve keyword '' into field. Choices are: __app___article_user_dis_likes, __app___article_user_likes, __app___imageurl_user_dis_likes, __app___imageurl_user_likes, __app___review_user_dis_likes, __app___review_user_likes, __app___url_user_dis_likes, __app___url_user_likes, __app___videourl_user_dis_likes, __app___videourl_user_likes, article, date_joined, email, first_name, groups, id, imageurl, is_active, is_staff, is_superuser, last_login, last_name, logentry, password, review, url, user_permissions, username, userobjectpermission, videourl
   ```

Comment: Could not reproduce on 1.6.2, `URL.objects.get(pk=...).likes.all()` works as expected. Is your database schema up to date with your model definition? Which Django version are you running?

Comment: @lanzz Yes the database schema is up to date with the model definition, i used south to add likes and dis_likes. I am using Django 1.6

Comment: Can you provide the complete traceback you're getting?

Comment: @lanzz I have posted partial traceback

Comment: Please post the _full_ traceback. The `FieldError` exception you're getting does not seem to be about a `URL` instance, but for a `User` instance.

Comment: @lanzz The traceback originated at a template. The traceback is rather long and everything prior to the above partial traceback is related to templates and template tags. Besides, I have already stashed the changes and moved on to temp branch so that i can work on other parts of the project.

Comment: show user model's meta class

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think I have found the problem. I suppose the problem is with the name of my app which is `__app__`. Django field look up assumes everything before `__`(double underscore) is a field which in my case resolves to ``(empty string).

Always had hard time naming the default app and the project it lives in. Thought `__app__` was more pythonic and clever solution. I guess I should rename my app to just `app`. Hope this works.

Comment: `__app__` is not a good idea for _many_ reasons; instance attributes starting with `__` will be [mangled by the Python interpreter](http://docs.python.org/2/reference/lexical_analysis.html#reserved-classes-of-identifiers); documentation generally discourages use of custom `__*__` identifiers.

Answer (score 2):

This can happen if you attempt to use `__unicode__` or `__str__` in places where Django expects a field name. In my case I was trying to use `__unicode__`, because I give my models meaningful implementations and wanted to reuse it in the first column of tables.

To get around this I added

```
class AdminBase(admin.ModelAdmin):

    def natural_title(self, obj):
        return unicode(obj)

    natural_title.short_description = 'Title'
```

where `AdminBase` is a custom base class for my admin classes. I can now use `'natural_title'` as a field name and get the results I was seeking.