# Reverse relationship with several Foreign Key in Django. "FieldError. Cannot resolve keyword into field. Choices are..."

Tags: python, django

I know I am not the first one to ask this question but I can't find a solution. I have the following model

```
class Flat (models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User)
    agent = models.ForeignKey(User, null=True, blank=True, related_name='agent')
```

And I want to retrieve all Users who are associated to a flat which has a specific agent, knowing that agent has a OneToOne relationship with the User model. So I used the following lookup following [the docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/queries/#lookups-that-span-relationships) :

```
clients = User.objects.filter(flat__agent=specific_agent)
```

But I get the following error :

```
Cannot resolve keyword 'flat' into field
```

My guess is that the problem comes from the fact I have two FK - with the User model in my Flat model. So I tried to use [related_name](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.ForeignKey.related_name) and [related_query_name](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.ForeignKey.related_query_name), but nothing changes.

Any idea on where the problem could come from ? Thanks !

Comment: Does this help? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22329439/django-cannot-resolve-keyword-into-field-choices-are

Comment: @holandaGo Thanks, but it does not...

Comment: What happens if you add a specific `related_name="flat"` to the first ForeignKey?

Comment: @DanielRoseman I added the related_name then I syncdb and nothing changed

Comment: @Marcolac: syncdb will not modify existing fields, you need migrations for that. Other than that, @Daniel Roseman is right, or if you leave the `related_name` as it is, filter by: `User.objects.filter(agent=specific_agent)`

Comment: @andrean Thanks but I am not sure I need a migration for a related_name. And doing the query you wrote will not give me what I want...

Comment: You don't need a migration or syncdb, since related_name does not affect the database in any way.

Comment: oh damn right...sorry my mistake